# Difference between matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel() and .set_xlabel() in python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When setting parameters for a table using matplotlib, what is the difference between these two naming functions. I initially thought plt.xlabel was used for functional naming and .set_xlabel was used for object oriented naming but Im now confused

Comment: What specifically has caused you to be confused?

Comment: When is each one used. For example, is .set_xlabel used only for data frame objects? What are the use cases of each and how do they differ

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking about dataframes (pandas is not matplotlib), but it might help to read about the [Pyplot vs. Object-Oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).